# How to restrict FTP access to certian IPs while the web app is accessible over Internet in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are having multiple web apps running on Azure using PaaS offering.

The requirement is, though all the hosted applications(web apps) are accessible all over the internet, still only a specific number of users (say IPs) will only be allowed to do FTP on the Azure cloud environment.

I need some advise on how to achieve that.

Azure offers NSG for complete isolation and full control over managing inbound / outbound traffic to the Web apps but we believe to implement NSG, we need to implement Virtual Network and ASE before that.
but then, if all the web apps resides under the VNET, then whoever will access the applications will be needing to have VNET client in their local machines.

Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: Hi, what is NSG and ASE? It will be helpful to give the full name instead of acronyms. Thanks.

Comment: NSG is Network Security Group and ASE is App Service Environment. Sorry :)